# Is a transaction valid if it was signed weeks in the past?

Tags: transactions, nonce

I'd like to add scheduled transactions functionality to my chrome extension, but I don't want to ask the user for password input every time a scheduled tx is sent. My idea is to create and sign transactions then save them, and then send them when it's time.

I'm aware that a transaction must include a nonce, and if no transactions are sent in the mean time, the nonce shouldn't be a problem. But what if I wanted to send transactions after SIGNING the scheduled TX but before SENDING that scheduled TX? For example could a TX with nonce 2 be sent after a TX with nonce 3?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can send transaction with whatever nonce but they will be discarded if they are not the next nonce. So if you send a transaction with a nonce 3 before one with nonce 2, the one with 3 will be discarded by nodes as it does not follow the rules.

Just signing a transactions doesn't make it any more 'official' - nobody knows about it and it doesn't get processed in any way. So transactions matter only when they are sent to the network.

Otherwise if there are no newer transactions I don't see any problem with sending a transaction which was signed weeks ago.

Comment: I'm aware of what signing does and why things are signed, it's just that if a tx is signed with some nonce, the nonce cant be changed without re-signing the tx. I have a workaround but just wanted to make sure it's necessary. I assumed this was the case but was hoping there were rules specifically for forward-dated (forward-nonced) signed transactions